# How to login using UserID in JAVA BOX SDK

Tags: java, eclipse, sdk, box

I am using BOX JAVA SDK to access the box functionalities.

I've got enterpriseId and also userId to login into Box as an enterprise user.

I am able to login using enterpriseId but not with userId.

```
BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection boxjwtconnection=new BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection(userId,devedienttype.USER,clientId,clientSecret,jwtenrypref,null);
```

This is the exception I am getting when I am trying to login using userId.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.box.sdk.BoxAPIException: The API returned an error code: 401
at com.box.sdk.BoxAPIResponse.<init>(BoxAPIResponse.java:69)
at com.box.sdk.BoxAPIRequest.trySend(BoxAPIRequest.java:421)
at com.box.sdk.BoxAPIRequest.send(BoxAPIRequest.java:209)
at com.box.sdk.BoxAPIRequest.send(BoxAPIRequest.java:184)
at com.box.sdk.BoxUser.getCurrentUser(BoxUser.java:139)
```

Where I am doing mistakes? Any solutions?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to have your client_id user-enabled.  You can open ticket with Box or you can do it yourself through the new developer console.

Comment: How am I supposed to do that? I already got developer console. Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using the box-java-sdk, I don't think as-user works yet.

https://community.box.com/t5/Developer-Forum/404-when-trying-to-get-BoxFolder-Info-or-BoxFile-Info-JWT/m-p/25570#U25570

Comment: So using Enterprise id I am able to login ...but not with UserId ... I don't know why its not possible?